# How do i overcome additional '\' that i end with while combining two json files in python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to combine two json files but end with some weird "\" in my output.

```
import json

data1 = {'apple': 'good',"mango": "excellent"}

json_data1 = json.dumps(data1)

data2 = {'mustang': 'good',"camaro": "excellent"}

json_data2 = json.dumps(data2)

final_data = { 'fruit' : str(json_data1), 'car' : str(json_data2) }

json_final = json.dumps(final_data)

print(json_final)
```

Expectation:

```
{"fruit": "{"apple": "good", "mango": "excellent"}", "car": "{"camaro": "excellent", "mustang": "good"}"}
```

What I got:

```
{"fruit": "{\"apple\": \"good\", \"mango\": \"excellent\"}", "car": "{\"camaro\": \"excellent\", \"mustang\": \"good\"}"}
```

How do I overcome this issue?

Also, in my actual problem, I just get two JSON objects and I have no control over anything else.

Comment: When you say "just get two jsons", do you mean your input is `json_data1` and `json_data2`, not `data1` and `data2`?

Comment: Yes i meant  input is json_data1 and json_data2, not data1 and data2.

Comment: Then you want the "If Your Input Is Already JSON-Encoded" section of my answer.

Comment: Yes checked it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If Your Data Is Native Python Structures

Don't stringify or JSON-encode the included content separately at all. Keep your content as purely native data structures and only encode as JSON *once*.

Otherwise, when you run the first `json.dumps()` pass you're generating a string -- and when you call `json.dumps()` in a data structure that includes that string, you're generating a JSON sequence that encodes *the string*, not a JSON data structure that encodes the original dictionary that string was created to represent.

```
import json

data1 = {'apple': 'good',"mango": "excellent"}
data2 = {'mustang': 'good', "camaro": "excellent"}
final_data = { 'fruit' : data1, 'car' : data2 }
json_final = json.dumps(final_data)
```

---

#### If Your Input Is Already JSON-Encoded...

The safe approach is to decode into native structures before reencoding. That is:

```
json_data1 = '{"mango": "excellent", "apple": "good"}'
json_data2 = '{"camaro": "excellent", "mustang": "good"}'
final_data = { 'fruit': json.loads(json_data1), 'car': json.loads(json_data2) }
json_final = json.dumps(final_data)
```

The *unsafe* approach is to use string concatenation:

```
# DANGER: Will produce badly-formed output instead of throwing an exception if input is bad
json_data1 = '{"mango": "excellent", "apple": "good"}'
json_data2 = '{"camaro": "excellent", "mustang": "good"}'
json_final = '{ "fruit": %s, "car": %s }' % (json_data1, json_data2)
```

Comment: Why not `final_data = { 'fruit' : data1, 'car' : data2 }`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, ...okay, as-edited, that comment makes considerably more sense than did its initial incarnation.